# Define a string in python for loop using socket.gethostname()

Tags: python, sockets

So, I'm trying to use `socket.gethostname()` to return the name of a server for me. I then want to take the name of that server and change it to something else and store it as a variable.

For example, if a have a server called "MyTestServer", I want to get the name, then store it as a string 'test'. I thought the below code would work in PYthon, but it's not...any suggestions?

```
 for name in socket.gethostname():
        if name is 'MyTestServer':
            strjil = 'test'
```

Comment: What you are trying to solve is unclear to me. As pointed in the answers, the keyword "is" is wrong in this situation. But then you want to store that name in a string called "test". Am I right? You have to be aware that gethostname() returns the local host name, not the distant one. To change the name of the host you are running on, you need to use sethostname() which only works if you have sufficient rights.

Answer (score 1):

The `is` operator is used to compare the *identity* of objects. You need to use `==` to compare values:

```
if name == 'MyTestServer':
```

Here is a [reference](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in) on comparing objects in Python.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import socket
>>> name = socket.gethostname()
>>> if name == "MyTestServer":
...   strjil = "test"
...
```

(I am not sure how `strjil` is related to `name`, so I've left them as-is.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are only talking about the name of your own machine (the one running the code):

```py
import socket
# Get the local hostname as a string (a chain of characters)
myname = socket.gethostname()
# Compare this name to some value (another string) and do something special
# (This is an example)
if myname == "MyTestServer":
    print("You are running on the right host")
# If the name of the host is not the one expected, we can imagine to abort the
# program (just an example)
else:
    print("You may not run this script on that computer")
    exit(1) # Quit program

# You can try changing your own host name
try:
    socket.sethostname("NewName")
# This may fail because of permissions
except OSError as e:
    print("Could not change my own name:", e)
    exit(1) # Quit program
```

If you want to get the host name of a distant computer, you need to create a connection between them first. And you will not be able to force them to change their name using python that way.

```py
# Now, do something with other systems
# Create a listening socket on port 8888 and accept connection on it
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(("", 8888))
sock.listen(1)
conn, addr = sock.accept()
# Get some information about the client who connected to us
clientinfo = conn.getpeername()
# It is actually a tuple containing hostname and port
distantname, port = clientinfo
# Here you can also do something special with it
if distantname != "AcceptedClient":
    print("Intruder!!")
    sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    sock.close()
    exit(1)
# However, you cannot change that name, unless you ask the client politely to do
# that on his side
# Maybe for example:
sock.send(b"CHANGENAME NewClientName\n")
# Then the client would have code that reacts to that command and do the
# necessary
# ...
```